# Javascript regex: replace hyphen between characters only (not spaces)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace the hyphen between 2 characters in a string. The 2 characters can be *anything* but a space.

```
string.replace(/regex/g, '');
```

so

- dog-cat : dogcat
- dog - cat : *unchanged*
- 1-1 : 11
- 1 - 1 : *unchanged*
- $-$ : $$
- $ - $ : *unchanged*
- ^-^ : ^^
- ^ - ^ : *unchanged*
- etc...

Comment: `str = str.replace(/(\S)-(\S)/g, '$1$2');`

Comment: Your accepted solution [returns `11-11` for `1-1-1-1` input](https://regex101.com/r/wj2MK4/1), do you really want that? See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50565001/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex replace:

```
str = str.replace(/(\S)-(\S)/g, '$1$2');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/upw7al/1)

Here `(\S)-(\S)` matches a non-space character followed by hyphen followed by another non-space character. We are also capturing both adjacent characters in group and then in replacement we put back `$1$2`.

```js
const regex = /(\S)-(\S)/g;
const str = `dog-cat
dog - cat
1-1
1 - 1
$-$
$ - $
^-^
^ - ^`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, '$1$2');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex: `"dog-cat".replace(/(?=\S)(-)(?=\S)/g, '')`

Comment: this only replace string

Comment: that's not true, it also replaces specials chars, try the following: "$-$".replace(/(?=\S)(-)(?=\S)/g, '')

Comment: You probably meant to use `/(?<=\S)-(?=\S)/g`. However, the lookbehind  is not yet supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all `-` chars in between non-whitespace chars you should use

```
.replace(/(\S)-(?=\S)/g, '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0kqwzK/1).

Here,

- `(\S)` - maches and captures any non-whitespace char into Group 1
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=\S)` - (a positive lookahead assuring that) after the hyphen, there must be a char other than a whitespace. This char is not consumed, i.e. the regex index stays right before it, allowing to match that char with the next iteration (as `g` global modifier will allow matching all occurrences of a regex pattern in a string).

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /(\S)-(?=\S)/g;
var s = "dog-cat\ndog - cat\n1-1\n1 - 1\n$-$\n$ - $\n^-^\n^ - ^\n1-1-1-1";
console.log(s.replace(rx, '$1'));
```